# Question on Model Validation and Interpretation

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, boosting

I’m a beginner here who is trying to build a model for my personal project (albeit using data I got from my firm). The data is a call center dataset , and Im trying to predict the number of successful sales made per employee in the week based on several predictors (time at desk, log in time, calls made etc)

I’ve so far trained a GBM and I’ve gotten some predictions (for context, the range is from 0 to 10 sales made).

Here are my questions:

1. Now that I have my predictions, how do I separate the impact of each predictor like I would with Beta coefficients from a GLM?
   I’m trying to solve the question : what predictors contributes (quantitatively) to a caller’s sales volume?
   So with Beta coefficients I can say, for caller A, number of time spent at desk is the biggest driver to his/her sales volume.
   But since GBMs doesn’t have Beta coefficients, is there an alternative? Is SHAP for this purpose? Or do I need to just stick with a GLM?
2. What are the best ways to diagnose/validate my model? Given that this is a non binary classification, it seems that I can’t use ROC/gains curve/GINI to diagnose?
   I remember seeing somewhere that this still works with continuous outcomes, but I can no longer find that article! It says something like ROC can be used if I rank the outcomes by deciles or something like that....

Thank you all for reading, and any help or recommendations are much much appreciated for a noob like me :)
For context I am using R, so any package recommendations are welcomed!

Comment: Gradient boosting machines (GBM) and generalized linear models (GLM) are very different. Which one do you refer to?

Comment: I would like to use a GBM (and have done so). My question was more of how do I separate out the impacts of each predictor with the GBM, just like how the Beta coefficients can do so for a GLM.

Comment: For GBM, SHAP, specifically TreeSHAP can bring you some insights about the feature importance, feature interactions. This kind of model explanations are suggested to be the start of posthoc analysis, not the end.